# "uploaded file has no extension" error when trying to import product or customer information from CSV

Tags: error, import, magento-community

I am trying to import Product and Customer data into my new Magento install (CE 1.9.1) I have the CSV files correctly formatted based on the export files but when I upload and click on check data I get the error "uploaded file has no extension".

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The message is intended to mean that the filename of the file you are importing doesn't have a file extension. That is to say the file you are selecting to import is called something like `customers` rather than `customers.csv`. It attempts to validate the file extension as this determines what type of adapter to load (csv, xml, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If the file *does* have an extension it most likely means the file is not uploaded (completely) or is not readable by the script.
First make sure the file is present on the server in the correct folder, if not, here are some things to check:

- free disk space
- folder permissions on /var
- PHP settings like memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_execution_time

Also check the logs in /var/logs and those from Apache.

Answer (score -2):

Hi I get the same error with Magento 1.9.1. My file has the extension ".CSV". But when I try to upload with a another Browser (FireFox) then it works fine. Probably a JAVA plugin problem.